# Selecting all rows with a column that is contained in query result

Tags: sql, nested-select

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Master (
    url TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    masterId TEXT,
);

CREATE TABLE Version (
    verId TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    isPending INTEGER,
    masterId TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY(masterId) REFERENCES Master(masterId)
);
```

I want to select all pending `url`s. Meaning all urls from `Master` that has a row in `Version` with the same `masterId` and `isPending = 1`.

How to write such nested select?

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` the tables together.

Comment: You can't create those two tables like that. (Invalid foreign key...)

Comment: @jarlh Can you explain why?

Comment: A foreign key must reference a key. (Either the primary key or a unique constraint.)

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can't I just use something like: `@"SELECT url FROM Master WHERE masterId IN (SELECT masterId, FROM Version WHERE isPending = 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `join`

```
SELECT m.*
     , v.*
FROM   Master m
JOIN   version v
  ON m.masterId = v.masterId
WHERE  isPending = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the URL's that are pending then you could use an EXISTS

```
SELECT url
FROM Master m
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM Version v
  WHERE v.masterId = m.masterId
    AND v.isPending = 1
);
```